# Add milliseconds to timestamp (bash, unix)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, time, terminal

EDIT: This is apparently not possible, see Barmars answer below.

I use the command below a lot to create a timestamp for archiving purposes. I'd like to add milliseconds to the string. Is that possible? I use this script on both osx and linux, so a solution that works on both would be nice. Are seconds ever rounded up or down with or without milliseconds? (Are minutes rounded up or down?)

```
date -n +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this portably. See the [POSIX strftime specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html), it doesn't mention anything about milliseconds or nanoseconds.

Furthermore, the input to `strftime` is a `struct tm`. The specification of this structure is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) and it doesn't include anything more precise than seconds. Nanoseconds are in the `timespec` structure, but this is mostly used for time periods, not clock time, and there's no requirement for the system to maintain the clock time to more than second resolution.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't, but I thought I'd mention that in `ts`, you can use "%.S" for millisecond precision. Just in case you were using `date` to timestamp output lines.

Answer (score 2):

%N gives you nanoseconds and you could divide that by 1000000

Comment: in osx terminal "date -n +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N" gives me "20130625224326N" is it because the bash version is old?

Comment: What does the version of bash have to do with this? It's the `date` command.

Comment: I don't think `%N` is portable, it's not in the OS X `strftime()` man page.

Comment: @ Tor  I just assumed it wour work for osx, can you upgrade your date command?

Comment: I think to get milliseconds from nanoseconds, it would probably be more useful to divide by `1e6`, rather than to multiply... Unless you really want femtoseconds...

Comment: @dakillakan The `date` command just calls the library function `strftime()`. If the library doesn't support it, the command won't do any better.

Comment: Of course, on OSX one might uses `gdate` (from `brew install coreutils`) which _does_ support `%N`...

Answer (score 1):

You may try `%3N`, which works in git bash for windows and Debian 9.