# Get timestamp including milliseconds

Tags: ruby, command-line, time

I use this command a lot on OS X to create a timestamp for archiving purposes:

```
date -n +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

This gives an answer in this format:

```
20130625230005
```

I'd like to add milliseconds to the end of this string. Is it possible to get that with Ruby from the command line?

It's unfortunately not possible to do this on OS X by adding something to the command above: [Add milliseconds to timestamp (bash, unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307086/add-milliseconds-to-timestamp-bash-unix)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[DateTime#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) has a `%L` format specifier for milliseconds:

```bash
$ ruby -e "puts Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L')"
20130625141141827
```

**Update:** To answer the question in your comment, yes, this is possible.  Clicking on the documentation link above, there's `%N` for fractional second digits.  To remove the last digit from above, use `%2N` rather than `%L` (`%3N` is equivalent to `%L`).  To get just deciseconds, use `%1N`.

Comment: thanks! is it possible to remove one digit or get desiseconds (I guess I thought deciseconds were milliseconds)

Comment: @TorThommesen You're welcome!  And yes, that's possible; I updated my answer to explain how.